# Where I can find vector or PSD files for Sitecore topology drawings?

Tags: azure

At https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/sitecore-configurations-and-topology-for-azure.html there is topology drawing shown (like https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/image/15c1cb631a985c.png). Is there vector, or Visio, or PSD files of this to ease modifications of expected topology for our particular use-case?

Answer (score 4):

While I am not sure if there is a template available for the specific topologies, they are built using the Microsoft Cloud Symbol/Icon set which you can download here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41937.  Probably not the head start you were looking for, but the icon set will allow you to recreate diagrams with the same look and feel as the originals you are referencing.

Comment: Thank you. This icon set I saw - but it is so tedious to do those drawings :)... Got a suggestion to use https://www.draw.io/ as well for doing drawings myself on Sitecore slack